# $\lim_{x\to0}2^{\cot x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

> $$\lim_{x\to0}2^{\cot x}$$

So it turns out that the limit does not exist but here's the thing. I can't compute this limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\cot x}$$

this is all I did $$\lim_{x\to0}{\cot x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\cos x }{x\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x}{x}$$

then nothing comes to mind. I feel like this is a really easy problem but I've been trying to solve thins for over an hour and I'm stuck. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: This limit does not exist either. For x close to 0, cos x is basically 1 so it has the same behaviour as 1/x

Comment: Use ln, ln is continuous

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{\sin x}=\infty$, $\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1{\sin x}=-\infty$, and $\lim_{x\to0}\cos x=1$, you have$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\cot x=\infty\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to0^-}\cot x=-\infty.$$So$$\lim_{x\to0^+}2^{\cot x}=\infty\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to0^-}2^{\cot x}=0.$$

Comment: oooooh, thanks! finally!

Answer (score 1):

Write $2^{\cot x}$ as $\exp(\cot x\log 2)$. Since the exponential function is continuous,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^+}\exp(\cot x\log2)&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to0^+}\cot x\log 2\right) \\
&= \exp\left(\infty\log 2\right) \\
&= \infty \, .
\end{align}
The same approach can be made for the left-hand limit, and the comparison of the two shows us that two-sided limit does not exist.